# IntelliJ renames directory instead of creating new directory

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to create new directories in my web application. I right click on `main/java/resources/static` and select `New Directory` after I enter the name "js", it just renames `static` to `static.js`. Using Windows explorer to view the directory shows that it did actually create the `js` directory under `static`, but now I have the issue of wanting to create another subdirectory under static, "css". So I right click on `static.js` and select `New Directory`, after entering "css" it renames `static.js` to `static.js.css`. When using windows explorer to view the directory, it created the css folder at `static/js/css`. This seems very weird, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the **Flatten Packages** option:

[image: flatten]

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't rename anything, it's just a visual representation of Java packages to take less space in the tree (there is also an option to hide empty middle packages).

Comment: I actually do have this disabled, it's one of the things I tried. Hmmm

Comment: So there is no way to create multiple directories under `src/main/resources/static`?

Comment: @zero01alpha I can't reproduce what you describe in  IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4, [check this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/mL5qfTN.png). Both source and resource directories can display folders fine.

Comment: Oh, it must just be something weird with my local installation then, I'll mark this as accepted.